# If $\sin(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)=a,$ denote $|\sin(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)|$ in terms of $a$

Tags: trigonometry, absolute-value

I attempted to solve it using the following identities: $1.\ a^2-b^2.\ 2.\ (a\pm b)^2.\ 3. a^3\pm b^3.\ 4.\ (a\pm b)^3.$

Since none of my efforts led me to the correct answer (which is $\sqrt{2-a^2}$), I found it better not to write my lengthy work towards solving it.

I mostly got the expression $2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha).$ So, any helpful hints, comments or answers are welcome!

Comment: `I attempted to solve it using the following identities` The following works, instead: $\,(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2=2(a^2+b^2)\,$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$1+2\sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}=a^2,$$
which says
$$2\sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}=a^2-1.$$
Id est,
$$|\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha|=\sqrt{1-2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}=\sqrt{1-(a^2-1)}=\sqrt{2-a^2}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}
\sin b+\cos b&=a\\
\sin^2 b+2\sin b\cos b+\cos^2 b&=a^2\\
-2(\sin^2b+\cos^2b)&\quad -2\\
-\sin^2b+2\sin b\cos b-\cos^2 b&=a^2-2\\
-(\sin b-\cos b)^2&=a^2-2\\
(\sin b-\cos b)^2&=2-a^2\\
|\sin b-\cos b|&=\sqrt{2-a^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! But it's a bit ambiguous to me. Could you edit your answer to show the relationship between these expressions, how you got $2$ in the second row from the top?

Comment: As I stated at the end, you use $\sin^2b+\cos^2b=1$.  In particular, you subtract this quantity twice.  Do you need more than this?

Comment: Yes, it would be good.

Comment: How does that look?

Comment: I couldn't get back to you on time, but now, your answer is clear to me and satisfying. Everything is much more plain. Big thanks!